# C++ [templates] Finding proper container by type

Tags: c++, templates, containers, type-traits

I'm working on a learning project and I'm messing with some resource loader which I'm trying to define it as generic as possible when I got stucked while defining containers by type and then fetch them.

For instance if I have a `container<TypeA>` and `container<TypeB>` how can I define which one to pick depending on a function parameter?

As a dummy example:

```
template <class T>
void DoFoo(T&& t) 
{
  // How to determine which container to use?
  container<TypeA>.Add(t); 
  container<TypeB>.Add(t); 
}
```

For more extended context of the actual code:

```
class ResourceManager {
    // Resources will be referenced by name --> "Main font", "Background music"...
    using ResourceName = std::string_view;
    // Functor to convert name to hash, in this case using std::hash (good enough).
    using ResourceIDFactory = std::hash<ResourceName>;
    // Hash type or resource ID will be the result of hashing the name: std::hash("Main Font").
    using ResourceID = std::invoke_result<ResourceIDFactory, ResourceName>::type;
        
        // Resource Handle is defined by it's own type trait.
    template<typename T>
    using ResourceMap = std::unordered_map < ResourceID, Resources::Resource<T>::HandleTy>;

public:
    template <typename Resource, typename ... Args>
    auto Load(ResourceName name, Args&& ... args) {
        ResourceID id = GetResoruceID(name);
        if (auto ptr = IsResourceLoaded<Resource>(id))
        {
            return *ptr;
        }

        auto handle = resourceLoader.Load<Resource>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                // How do I find the correct containter to add the new handle?

    }

private:

    template<typename T>
    Resources::Resource<T>::HandleTy* IsResourceLoaded(ResourceID id) {
        // this is one of the worst functions I've ever wrote.
        // Problem resides on finding the right container by resource type
        // Might be solvable with some SFINAE and some dark magic. WIP.
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Font>)
        {
            auto it = fontResources.find(id);
            return (it != fontResources.end()) ? &(*it) : nullptr;
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Music>) {
            auto it = musicResources.find(id);
            return (it != musicResources.end()) ? &(*it) : nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            // this might run unto compilation issue as it not type checked.
            auto it = soundResources.find(id);
            return (it != soundResources.end()) ? &(*it) : nullptr;
        }
    }

    inline ResourceID GetResoruceID(ResourceName name)
    {
        return IdFactory(name);
    }

private:
    Resources::Loader   resourceLoader;
    ResourceIDFactory   IdFactory;
        // Ugly way, could not find a proper way to dynamically generate containers by type
    ResourceMap<Font>   fontResources;
    ResourceMap<Music>      musicResources;
    ResourceMap<Sound>      soundResources;
};
```

I'm using C++latest (so I can use some c++23 features if needed), but so far I'm clueless about which direction I should go.

Note: I'm not using boost, as I prefer to learn from scratch.

Thanks in advance!

---

Some experiments I did that doesn't worked or don't like the outcome:

- Work with `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<A,B>)` this will force to check for all the types one by one which doesn't scale well and bloats all the functions. I'd like to discard this option.
- Try to Generate a Hash by type with static template function and get it's adress to have a higher level container: `map<Typehash, Container<T>` the problem is the value type (`Container<T>`) is not homogenuous.

---

Comment: Maybe use map like this `map<Typehash, std::any>` and try to `std::any_cast<T>` in `IsResourceLoaded` function or use CRTP technique in your `Font`, `Music` and `Sound` classes derive them from `Resource<T>` and use `std::variant` and `std::visit`

Comment: Hmm so bascially type erasure and then cast back to recover the type, this might work, ty for the suggestion.

About the variant I'm a little against in this scenario as it will limit the options, and every time I added a new Type it will force to update the variant declaration and extend the visitor functor.

Comment: In the class: `template<typename T> Resources::Resource<T>::HandleTy* IsResourceLoaded(ResourceID id);` Only declared, no definition. Outside the class: `template<> Resources::Resource<Font>::HandleTy* ResourceManager::IsResourceLoaded(ResourceID id) { /* implement using fontResources */ }` Repeat for the other resource types.